# How can I search for a past clipboard item in Ditto based on the time it was placed in the clipboard (= saved in Ditto)?

Tags: windows, search, clipboard, time, ditto

Ditto is a program that saves each item placed on the clipboard allowing access to any of those items at a later time. How can I search for a past clipboard item in Ditto based on the time it was placed in the clipboard (= saved in Ditto)?